# Route and Post parameter in the Yii2 with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I call AJAX-request in my jQuery-script. I have created the controller (AjaxController) and method actionRequest inside this. JQuery sends this request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: location.origin + '/web/index.php?r=ajax/request',
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'param': 32},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {result = data}
});
```

and this code is in controller's script:

```
public function actionRequest() {
    $param = Yii::$app->request->post('param');
    echo json_encode($param);
}
```

Controller has accepts this option and send its back. JavaScript displays this option (result) with the help of "alert()". If I send it with GET methods, then all works correctly and window displays "32". But if I change this request into the "POST", window displays "undefined". If I send request to my PHP-script (path: /web/php), then all works correctly too. And if I will delete all code from my controller and leave only:

```
<?php
    $param = $_POST['param'];
    echo json_encode($param);
?>
```

and ask the script directly, then all works correctly too...

There are all signs which mean that error is in the framework, when I use AJAX-method POST. Because if I write this code inside my controller:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$file = fopen($root . '/text.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file, '1');
fclose($file);
```

then I send GET-request, and code is completed and create file in the root directory on the site. But if I change request into the POST, then file is not created.

---

Source of my controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class AjaxController extends Controller {
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actions() {
        return [
            'error' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex() {
            return '';
    }

    public function actionRequest() {
        $param = Yii::$app->request->post('param');
        echo json_encode($param);
    }
}

?>
```

My UrlManager:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'suffix' => '/',
    'rules' => [
        '' => 'site/index',
        'register' => 'site/register'
    ]
]
```

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post)`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your UrlManager settings, try to change your ajax url to this instead.

```
url: location.origin + '/ajax/request/',
```

Just append the controller name, action name, and trailing forward slash.

The reasons are

- you set `enablePrettyUrl` to `true`
- `showScriptName` to `false`
- `suffix` to `/`

I have tested this and it works for both `GET` and `POST` type.

Just remember to change the function to obtain `GET` and `POST` param accordingly.